# Определение реальной высоты строки RichEdit в Delphi

Tags: delphi, редактор-текста

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnSetHeightClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, Max: Integer;
begin
  Max := 0;
  Canvas.Font.Assign(redt.Font);

  for i := 0 to Length(redt.Text) do
    if Max < Canvas.TextHeight(redt.Text[i + 1])then
      Max := Canvas.TextHeight(redt.Text[i + 1]);

  redt.Height := 4 * Max;
end;
```

С помощью данного кода выставляю высоту, допустим, для четырех строк. Выходит следующее:

[example01 http://savepic.ru/10588114.jpg](http://savepic.ru/10588114.jpg)

Некоторые буквы на последней строке **обрезаются**(Буквы: "**у**", "**р**", "**д**"). Можно, конечно, прибавить **несколько пикселей** и будет нормально, но если увеличить/уменьшить шрифт, то все собьется. Так если придется под каждый размер подбирать свою цифру, что ни есть хорошо. Также замечена проблема что бывают видны элементы символов от следующей строки, идущей за последней видимой.

**Как можно измерить реальную высоту строки**, чтобы каждая строка умещалась полностью и не видно было элементов символов от строки, которая идет следом за последней видимой (на рисунке это четвертая строчка)?

Comment: Поискать в ричедит значения междустрочного интервала, интервала перед абзацем и добавить их к "технической" высоте 4 строк?

Comment: Думаю, тут к высоте нужно добавить размер бордера. Рассчитать его можно с помощью `AdjustWindowRect`.

Comment: Все значения равны нулю, если смотреть через EM_GETPARAFORMAT, без предварительного выставления значений параметрам через EM_SETPARAFORMAT.

Answer (score 2):

**UPD:** Размеры отступов у меня корректно вычислялись для шрифта Times New Roman, 14-го размера. Общая высота составляет 6 пикселей, ее можно спокойно подставлять к расчётам на любом размере шрифта. На других размерах шрифта замечено некорректное вычисление высоты отступов.

Спасибо товарищу [Mega](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/8766/mega) за наводку. Прилагаю листинг кода:

```
function TfrmMain.GetLastVisibleLine(RichEdit: TRichEdit): Integer;
const
  EM_EXLINEFROMCHAR = WM_USER + 54;
var
  r: TRect;
  i: Integer;
begin
{
  The EM_GETRECT message retrieves the formatting rectangle
  of an edit control.
}
  RichEdit.Perform(EM_GETRECT, 0, Longint(@r));
  r.Left := r.Left + 1;
  r.Top  := r.Bottom - 2;
{
  The EM_CHARFROMPOS message retrieves information about the character
  closest to a specified point in the client area of an edit control
}
  i := RichEdit.Perform(EM_CHARFROMPOS, 0, Integer(@r.topleft));
{
  The EM_EXLINEFROMCHAR message determines which
  line contains the specified character in a rich edit control
}
  Result := RichEdit.Perform(EM_EXLINEFROMCHAR, 0, i);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  r: TRect;
begin
  redt.Lines.LoadFromFile('text.txt');

  r.TopLeft.X := 0;
  r.TopLeft.Y := 0;
  r.BottomRight.X := redt.ClientWidth;
  r.BottomRight.Y := redt.ClientHeight;
  AdjustWindowRect(r, WS_BORDER, False);

  BordersHeight := r.BottomRight.Y - (GetLastVisibleLine(redt) * GetCharHeight);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnSetHeightClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  CharHeight: Integer;
begin
  Canvas.Font.Assign(redt.Font);
  CharHeight := GetCharHeight;

  redt.Height := (4 * CharHeight) + BorderHeight;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnSetFontClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if dlgFont.Execute then
    redt.Font.Assign(dlgFont.Font);
end;

function TfrmMain.GetCharHeight: Integer;
var
  i, Max: Integer;
begin
  Max := 0;
  Canvas.Font.Assign(redt.Font);

  for i := 0 to Length(redt.Text) do
    if Max < Canvas.TextHeight(redt.Text[i + 1])then
      Max := Canvas.TextHeight(redt.Text[i + 1]);

  Result := Max;
end;
```

Пройдемся по коду:

Функция **GetLastVisibleLine** определяет номер последней видимой строки.

На событии **OnShow** формы узнаем общую высоту верхнего и нижнего отступов в пикселях(храним не в локальной переменной и вообще на время показа формы не изменяем значение).

Процедура **btnSetHeightClick** висит на кнопке и выставляет новую высоту для **RichEdit** с учетом общей высоты верхнего и нижнего отступов и количества строк(у меня количество строк равно четырем).

Функция **GetCharHeight** определяет текущую высоту символа в **RichEdit**.

Данный пример корректно выставляет(по крайней мере я так считаю, много не тестировал) высоту **RichEdit** для указанного количества строк. При изменении шрифта пересчет высоты тоже корректный. Обрезаний элементов символов строки и показ элементов символов от строки, следующей за последней видимой не обнаружены.

Answer (score 1):

```
CharHeight := Canvas.TextHeight(redt.Text[1]);
```

не всегда вернёт то что надо (например, если `Text[1]` - пробел, или вообще текста нет), тогда уж

```
CharHeight := Canvas.TextHeight('Wj');
```

Только учитывайте, что в RichEdit могут быть разные шрифты даже в одной строке, в этом случае ничего это не сработает.

---

Если же вам надо просто сделать высоту всего ричэдита по размеру текста, то я делал так, например:

```
procedure THelpPopup.reHelpResizeRequest(Sender: TObject; Rect: TRect);
begin
  BoundsRect := Rect; // выставляем размер формы равной размеру RichEdit
end;
```

И, соответственно, изначально размер ричедита делал минимальный (так же перед сменой содержимого).

P.S: Код - обработчик события `OnResizeRequest` у `TRichEdit`.

Comment: Учту, код подправил. Вообще у меня не предвидится использование нескольких шрифтов в одном RichEdit'е.

Comment: Я расширил ответ, по сравнению с комментарием, добавил как изменить размер формы по сравнению с текстом в `TRichEdit`.

Comment: Увидел. Полезный "костыль" :)